# Associate adjunct professor to Assistant adjunct professor in USA

Tags: ranking

Is it possible that an Associate adjunct professor becomes  assistant adjunct professor in USA university within same department of that university?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely much more common than for non-adjuncts. The protections for adjuncts are pretty weak generally. However, there are situations in which adjuncts are unionized and then the union rules would apply.

Also, the typical adjunct position is a fixed term contract that might be renewed or not. The nominal rank would be part of the contract.

But possible? Certainly. Not common, though.